# How to reference logo image multiple times in Excel 2007

Tags: excel, vba

Got a company logo need to use on several worksheets. How can I use and reference just one instance of the image to keep file size down, or does it matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter. I just inserted a 20 K image in an Excel file, copied it about 100 times using Ctrl-Drag, and it only increased the file size by 2K.

**Edit**

Even if you import it (using Insert Picture...) repeatedly, it seems to be able to tell that it's the same photo, and the file size only increases negligibly (less than 1K).